# Access Pod information using Master Public IP in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I can get Pods information using http://localhost:8001/api/v1/pods from inside my cluster.

Is there any way to get pod informations using http://master-public-ip:8001/api/v1/pods ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the master only exposes HTTPS to the public internet, not HTTP. You should be able to hit `https://admin:password@master-public-ip/api/v1/pods/`, where `password` is the generated password for the admin user. This can be found either in the `.kube/config` file on your machine, or in the `/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv` file on the master.

E.g. on the master VM:

```
$ cat /srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv 
mYpASSWORD,admin,admin
unused,kubelet,kubelet
...
```

Or on your machine:

```
$ cat ~/.kube/config
...
- name: my-cluster
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ...
    client-key-data: ...
    password: mYpASSWORD
    username: admin
...

$ curl --insecure https://admin:mYpASSWORD@master-public-ip/api/v1/pods/
...
```

To avoid using `--insecure` (i.e. actually verify the server certificate that your master is presenting), you can use the `--cacert` flag to specify the cluster certificate authority from your `.kube/config` file.

```
$ cat ~/.kube/config
...
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: bIgLoNgBaSe64eNcOdEdStRiNg
    server: https://master-public-ip
  name: my-cluster
...

$ echo bIgLoNgBaSe64eNcOdEdStRiNg | base64 -d > ca.crt

$ curl --cacert=ca.crt https://admin:mYpASSWORD@master-public-ip/api/v1/pods/
...
```

Comment: http://admin:pass@master-public-ip:8001/api/v1/pods it says - <h3>Unauthorized</h3> 

~/.kube/config file looks like–  
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: cluster-admin
  user:
     client-certificate-data: (somethings)
     client-key-data: (somethings)
     password: pass
    username: admin

Comment: Hmmm. It sounds like your .kube/config file may not be up to date with your current cluster. Does `kubectl get nodes` work? You can also look at the `/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv` file on the master.

Comment: Another way to hit the API directly from your local machine is to use kubectl's proxy command: `kubectl proxy` should start a server on `http://localhost:8001` using all of the credentials that kubectl knows about. Then you can `curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/pods` from your local machine.

Comment: I want to hit the api from my local pc's browser and want to get the information. But, it still says Unauthorized.

Comment: In that case, the easiest way is to use the kubectl proxy method.